# Updating/compile sendmail script not working.

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have wrote a script to update sendmail and compile on unix system
I put those lines

```
if [ ! -e $CWD/src/$NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz.sig ]
then
    echo "$NAME-$VERSION signatures missing"
    wget -c $SIGSOURCE -O $CWD/src/sendmail.$VERSION.tar.gz.sig
else
    echo
fi

if [ ! -e $CWD/src/$NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz ]
then
    echo "$NAME-$VERSION source missing"
    wget -c $SOURCE -O $CWD/src/sendmail.$VERSION.tar.gz
else
    echo
fi
```

Of course SIGSOURCE and SOURCE are defined
The problem is,even if file tar.gz and tar.gz.sig are
on directory $CWD/src the command wget run and waste
a lot of time for ftp connection.
What's wrong with this code?

Comment: One thing that is wrong, but it *may* not be a contributing factor, is not quoting your variables...

Comment: LOL was only an error syntax i use - instead of . because usually tar.gz are archived as name-version.tar.gz ,sendmail use name.version.tar.gz add your comment as answer so i can vote